# Why do I only have a link-local ipv6 address?

Tags: ipv6

I thought ipv6 solves the address problems. I was under the (obviously false?) assumption that I'd get an ipv6 address assigned to my machine at home and I would be able to use if (my ISP supports ipv6).

Why does `ip -6 address` only show a link-local address on my box?

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::<address>/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Can my router (via its dhcp) assign one to me? Or is this something I have to request from the ISP?

Basically I want to register a DNS address with that AAAA record and ipv6 address.

Comment: does your router have an IPv6 address? Does it support IPv6 at all? Have you configured it correctly?

Comment: Talk with your ISP. ServerFault is explicitly not covering home networks, only *business* networks.

Comment: I fiddled around my router, and indeed, it had ipv6 disabled! So after enabling it, I finally got an ipv6 address

Comment: Consider answering your own question, ideally a good answer with details like which router, where is the enable toggle, basics of your network design, and which ISP.

Comment: I did consider, but after @vidarlo 's answer, I was hesitating.

Comment: @transient_loop go ahead - an answered question is good anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my local ISP supports ipv6 - but my router had ipv6 disabled.

The router is a TP-Link TL-WR940N.

I only had to navigate to "IPv6 support" and in the configuration there hit the checkmark for "Enable", accept all the defaults, and then Save.

After that, I disconnected my device from the network, then reconnected, and I obtained an ipV6 address.